# Convert String to Double in android

Tags: android

I have a string 14469562 and I want to convert it to Double.But after converting a get a different value than the excepted value.

This is the code that I did :

```
String s="14469562 ";
double d = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();
```

My result is 1.4469562E7 which is wrong. How can I convert this ?

Comment: It seems pretty right to me, if you multiply 1.4469562 by 10^7 you get 14469562

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing was done correctly.

The "problem" you have is with how your double is represented in string. As it is big value it was used [Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) to represent it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using the following:

```
String s="14469562";
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

PS: You have white character in you s string, correct or trim it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(s.trim());
```